# Does an object destruction invalidate pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, destructor

In the code below, is `s`still pointing to valid memory after s1 is destroyed ? If yes, how does that work ? If no, anything we can do to avoid it ?

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    S(){std::cout<<"S()\n";}
    ~S(){std::cout<<"~S()\n";}
};

int main(){
    S *s;
    {
        S s1;
        s=&s1;
    }
}

//output:
//S()
//~S()
```

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: *"If no, anything we can do to avoid it ?"* - Now that, is the million dollar question. And it mostly revolves around program design and training people

Comment: I think the best way to avoid this is experience. This is something I never do because I know this is Undefined Behavior.